# How json data is handled by the parser

Tags: json, parsing, security, html-parsing

I was reading [**Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet**](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) and it's says on rule 3.1

> Ensure returned Content-Type header is application/json and not
> text/html. This shall instruct the browser not misunderstand the
> context and execute injected script

is this mean that if i want to embed json data in html page and this data contains tags for example < script >alert(/XSS/)< /script > (without space) this shouldn't work because the parser won't read the tags, so in this case we won't need encoding, am I right ?!, because owasp says after that, we should do **HTML ENTITY ENCODING** as well, so i'm wondering why should we ?

I juat started to learn about parsers so forget my lack of knowledge

Comment: Those are alternatives. One alternative is to send the data as application/json. I don't know why they think this isn't always practical (or "performant"), but I suppose it depends on the architecture of your server. So if you choose to send the data embedded in HTML, then you should make sure you entity-encode special characters. (Entity encoding characters in an `application/json` document won't work.)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding to xss site attacks it's not the parser that will cause an issue. Let's take an example you got a request from compromised browser. Sample below

`{ "Name": "<script>alert('test');</script>" }`

And the same input request parameter from browser you are using in your response to the client with out any encoding or checking.

When the client browser tries to use this field to display the name of the browser like hello , Name. The user will get an alert. Which is not desirable. Always we have to restrict and reject requests from accepting any tags so which will eradicate any scripting issues.

Am no expert in security issues. But it's always better to reject requests with tags in json.